# Ubuntu 18.04 "Web Content" & "WebExtension" high CPU usage

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, cpu-usage, visual-studio-code

I'm here to talk about a strange phenomenon.
I'm on a Ubuntu 18.04 Xfce.
Firefox 68.0.1 (64-bit)
Chrome 76.0.3809.87 (64-bit)
VSCode 1.36.1 (64-bit)

To resume, I have some very high CPU usage with `WebExtensions` and `Web content`, but only for like 1 min or so then it drops. Making `Firefox` unusable during the high usage. Circling "dots" for loading...

If I open `Firefox` alone then there is no problems, I even can open two dozens of tabs without experiencing a "freezing".

But the problem arises if I start `Chrome` or `Code`, with `Firefox` already on. As soon as I startup `Code/Chrome` 3 or 4 `Web Content` processes rise and use around 56% each (sometimes more) of my CPU (`top`) which make `Firefox` totally unusable. But not for `Chrome` nor `Code`, those can be used normally straight after startup.

The strange thing is when I startup `Chrome/Code` alone without `Firefox`, commands like `Web Content` & `WebExtensions` never get listed in `top`...

So my first question is: **What is going on here?**
and the second is: **How to prevent it?**

PS: I have already tried to disable all extensions/add-ons in Firefox, Chrome or Code but the behavior is the same.

Comment: Like I said, it is out of resources at `chrome` or `code` startup if `firefox` is already running but only for a minute, then I can use all three of them at max.

Comment: What??? No I disagree, You haven't read well enough what I've said. I'm not running out of resources if I startup, in this order, `code` > `chrome` > `firefox`. With this order or `chrome` before `code`, I can use all of them without reaching out the maximum of resources available... So where is my answer @dsstorefile1 ???

Comment: Same here. Firefox has symptoms above when Chrome starts: all 4 cores 100% (ff - ~ 76%). I have not checked, but maybe somehow desktop notifications are to blame? (Cant find that advice on how to switch them to another way). And to be clear: System is not our of memory. It just Firefox goes wild for a minute or so. And no VSCode required

Comment: Has anyone opened a firefox bug for this? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: I've opened a bug since it seems like a general problem with linux systems. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1580016